# Is the ceiling above a shower a "wet" or "damp" location?

Tags: electrical, shower, recessed-lighting, wet

I want to install recessed lights in my bathroom, in particular in the shower.  The definition for a "wet location" in the Canadian Electrical Code is something like "where it might get sprayed with water".  According to that, I would think the shower ceiling is a wet location, but most lights I've seen advertised for shower use are listed as "damp" (even a few "dry") location.  So... which one is it?  (I'm in Ontario, Canada).

The NEC seems a bit more specific than the CEC regarding lights above a shower/bath, but even then it's not clear what they mean by "subject to shower spray" (direct, indirect?).  The ceiling wouldn't normally get sprayed, but it's of course possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ceiling surface should be considered as a wet location, as it could be sprayed by water as you said. However, the above ceiling space is not in direct contact with water as the ceiling itself is blocking the potential spray.

The trim for the fixture must be wet location listed, whereas the fixture itself would be damp listed. (The fixture would only be dry depending on the height of the ceiling over the shower itself)